# how to make the jdbc mysql databse connection live

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, jdbc

below is my hibernate.xml file this file , for any query in sql i will use session factory for query but in this i am using a property name dataSource where it is refered to database connection,so for every query i am calling session factory and and for every call it is calling dataSource and making a new connection rather than that i want to make only one connection and make multiple queries one for each  request is it possible

i am using hibernate for sql queries

i am using below hibernate.xml as i have learnt from http://www.mkyong.com/spring/maven-spring-hibernate-mysql-example/

hibernate.xml:

```
<property name="dataSource">
  <ref bean="dataSource"/>
</property>

<property name="hibernateProperties">
   <props>
     <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
     <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
   </props>
 </property>

 <property name="mappingResources">
<list>
       <value>resources/database/Token.xml</value>
</list>
  </property>   

</bean>
```

datasource.xml:

```
<bean id="dataSource" 
         class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
   <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/get"/>
   <property name="username" value="root"/>
   <property name="password" value="password"/>
  <property name="initialSize" value="3"/>
   <property name="minPoolSize" value="1" />
<property name="maxPoolSize" value="3" />
</bean>

</beans>
```

Update: i have made my code connection pooling but how to make it open only one connection at start of application and use same connection for every request

as you can see for every call to session factory it calls dataSource  and it makes a connection i want to stop it

Comment: How do you know that it keeps reopening new connections? Can you attach logs to confirm this?

Comment: as it is calling dataSourse bean every time i thought it will reopen connection i will check logs and come bak

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two considerations.
First of all is that you can configure all your beans in only one xml file, not need to keep different files for hibernate and spring (the Spring one is enough).

Second: you can use a datasource that supports pooling connection and more configuration like [C3P0](http://sourceforge.net/projects/c3p0/). 
An example of how to declare it is:

```
<bean id="yourDataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClass" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/get" />
    <property name="user" value="username" />
    <property name="password" value="password" />
    <property name="minPoolSize" value="1" />
    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="3" />
    <property name="preferredTestQuery">
      <value>select null from dual</value>
    </property>
    <property name="testConnectionOnCheckin">
      <value>true</value>
    </property>
    <property name="idleConnectionTestPeriod">
      <value>1000</value>
    </property>
  </bean>
```

Comment: yeah i can make connection pooling but after that for every request i am calling session factory and every time it is making a db connection i want solution for that? i got solution for connection pooling thank you

Answer (score 1):

If you want to reuse connections, you need to use `DataSource` implementation which supports connection pooling.
The example [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-usagenotes-spring-config-connpooling.html) is for dbcp library. There is also [Tomcat](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jdbc-pool.html) implementation.

In order to use it you need to add the library to the dependencies and update the configuration of the DataSource with the implementation class and the configuration values for the connection pool.

Comment: yeah i can make connection pooling but after that for every request i am calling session factory and every time it is making a db connection i want solution for that? i got solution for connection pooling thank you

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I understand your issue but, how are you configuring your sessionfactory? Is your sessionfactory a spring bean?

If it is spring bean, then it is singleton by default, which means only one instance of sessionfactory exists for the entire application and is shared. In that case your assumption that you are creating a new sessionfactory which then creates a new datasource is wrong.

If you are manually creating your sessionfactory in code, then you need to implement the singleton design pattern by yourself.

```
private static SessionFactory seesionFactory = null;

    private static final SessionFactory makeSessionFactory()
    {
        try {
                      if (sessionFactory==null)
            seesionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
        } catch (HibernateException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
      return seesionFactory;    
    }
```